# Unable to pass parameters to powershell script via SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh

I'm trying to run a basic powershell script over ssh, the script is this:

```
param($passedUrl)

Function Launch-Site($url) {
    start chrome $url
}

Launch-Site $passedUrl
```

When I run this in powershell, in the correct directory, with the command

```
.\launchSite.ps1 google.co.uk
```

It runs as expected, it launches google chrome and goes to google.co.uk. However, when I use the same command from my ssh terminal (in the correct directory), it does nothing and gives me no errors as far as I can tell.
The default shell is set to powershell. I can run normal scripts that don't have any parameters passed to them, so I'm thinking this is just some security with windows that isn't letting me pass the parameter. Is there any way to get around/fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to use a PowerShell remote session. Something along the lines of:

```
New-PSSession -HostName HOSTNAME -UserName UserName
```

Hostname being an IP or FQDN. It will prompt you for a username for authentication. This can be stored also as a variable to pass into the module as well.